# pandas/python: replacing categorical values in dataframe through iteration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I created a database and I am trying to substitute the categorical variables with some numerical values
that I calculated via 'pivot'. In my code, I am trying to iterate through the whole dataframe and if the dataframe categorical columns cells have the same values as one of the elements in 'sublist_names', they should be replaced by the element in 'sublist_values' located in the same position as the value in sublist names.
For example, while iterating the dataframe and each of the categorical columns, the first value of column called 'Name' is the string 'tom'. 'tom' is exactly the 7th element in 'sublist_names', which means it should be replaced by the 7th element in 'sublist_values' which is equal to 150.

I was able to obtain all the needed values but when it comes to solving this last task by iterating the whole dataframe instead of working column by column, I am not sure how to do it.
I hope I explained clearly, but for any questions feel free to ask.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 10,6,'brown',200],
    ['nick', 15,5.10,'red',150],
    ['juli', 14,5.5,'black',170]
    ,['peter', 10,6,'blue',290],
    ['axel', 15,5.10,'yellow',190],
    ['william', 14,5.5,'yellow',170]
    ,['tom', 10,6,'orange',100],
    ['tom', 15,5.10,'brown',150],
    ['angela', 14,5.5,'black',160]
    ,['peter', 10,6,'purple',220],
    ['nick', 15,5.10,'orange',150],
    ['aroon', 14,5.5,'red',170] ]


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age','height','color','weight'])



categorical_variables= (df.select_dtypes('object') ) # categorical variables

categ_var_list=(list(categorical_variables))
print(categ_var_list)

condition_pivot_list_names=[]
pivot_values_list=[]
for i in categ_var_list:
    condition_pivot = df.pivot_table(index=i, values='weight', aggfunc=np.mean)
    pivot_names = (condition_pivot.index.values.tolist())
    condition_pivot_list_names.append(pivot_names)
    pivot_values_draft = ((condition_pivot.values.tolist()))
    pivot_values = [i[0] for i in pivot_values_draft]
    pivot_values_list.append(pivot_values)
print(condition_pivot_list_names, 'condition pivot list names')
print(pivot_values_list,'pivot values list')


sublist_names=[(sublists) for sublists in condition_pivot_list_names]
print(sublist_names)


sublist_values=[(sublists1) for sublists1 in pivot_values_list]
print(sublist_values)

def myfunc(x):
if x in sublist_names:
    index=sublist_names.index(x)
    return sublist_values[index]
return x

df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))

print(df['Name'])
```

This is what print( df[name]) shows:
0         tom
1        nick
2        juli
3       peter
4        axel
5     william
6         tom
7         tom
8      angela
9       peter
10       nick
11      aroon

And this is what should show:

0     150
1     150
2     170
3     255
4     190
5     170
6     150
7     150
8     160
9     255
10    150
11    170

Comment: You mean even if the `color` is the same, you want to substitute it with its correspond `weight` value?

Comment: no, I am trying to substitute in the dataframe the categorical values located in 'sublist_names' with the corresponding entries in 'sublist_values'. If for instance I want to replace the name 'tom' in the column 'Names', tom is located on the 7th entry of the first sublist in 'sublist_names', so it should be replaced with '150' the 7th entry of the first sublist in 'sublist_values'.

Comment: If you want to get an answer, you need to provide other users who are willing to help you, with these two things: 1.this is what data look like 2. This is the outcome I(you!) am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have two categorical values Name and Color. So you cam do something like this.

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: myfunc(x))
```

And than you can create a function myfunc() which will receive x from above code. What above code is doing is, it will iterate over the column one by one and pass value of each row one by one to the function. Inside the function you can define the logic to convert the categorical values something like this

```
def myfunc(x):
    if x in sublist_names:
        index=sublist_names.index(x)
        return sublist_values[index]
    return x
```

Do the same thing for the column Color.

Comment: the only way your code runs is if df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: myfunc(x)) comes after the function, and not before, which is not surprising because myfunc needs to be declared before being used.  Despite running, this code substitutes every single valuue in df[,Name'] with ALL values in 'sublist-values' instead of just one.

Comment: Yes, you have to declare a function before using it as python parses code from top to bottom. Hence, you cannot call a funtion before declaring it. Also, share your output when you run the code and also share what the data looks like.

Comment: I just edited the main question with your suggestion and its output and what the output should have been. I am sorry but I could not find out how to include the output properly. I hope my last edit helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.Name = np.where(df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)['Name'].cumcount().eq(0), df.Name, df.weight)
```

Output:

```
    Name    Age     height  color   weight
0   tom     10  6.0     brown   200
1   nick    15  5.1     red     150
2   juli    14  5.5     black   170
3   peter   10  6.0     blue    290
4   axel    15  5.1     yellow  190
5   william     14  5.5     yellow  170
6   100     10  6.0     orange  100
7   150     15  5.1     brown   150
8   angela  14  5.5     black   160
9   220     10  6.0     purple  220
10  150     15  5.1     orange  150
11  aroon   14  5.5     red     170
```

Comment: You can do the same thing also for `color` column if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I see your problem. Just write the code below before the function declaration.

```
sub_names=[]
sub_values=[]

for i in sublist_names:
    sub_names.extend(i)

for i in sublist_values:
    sub_values.extend(i)
```

Also dont forget to update variable names in myfunc().